# How to keep count of notifications when notification is not opened?

Tags: java, android, push-notification, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am sending the notifications from server to my app. I want to keep the count of notifications when notification arrives and I want to show it on the icon ,on text view that I want to make visible with the count of notification.

But the question is where should I do this stuff? I am using FCM so onMessageReceived is called when the app is in foreground.

For background I am sending data payload from server, but it also only catches the intent when the notification is clicked.

What is user did not click on notification and just removed it? Where to keep track of this?

For now my code is like this:

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";
    private String mOrderId, mBillId;
    private Boolean mNotification;
    private int notificationCount;
    private SessionData sessionData;

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
        sessionData = new SessionData(getApplicationContext());
        sessionData.add("notificationCount",0);

        notificationCount = sessionData.getInt("notificationCount",0);


        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

        // Check if message contains a data payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.describeContents());
        }

        // Check if message contains a notification payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        }

        //get data from server notification.


        sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody(), remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle());
    }

    //send notification

    private void sendNotification(String messageBody, String title) {


        mNotification = true;

        notificationCount ++;

        sessionData.add("notificationCount",notificationCount);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this,HomeActivity.class);
        if (!messageBody.equals("")) {
            intent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("notification", mNotification);
            intent.putExtra("title", title);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        }

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        long[] pattern = {500, 500, 500, 500, 500};
        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.login_logo_1)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(messageBody)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setVibrate(pattern)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
    }

}
```

In home activity

```
  if (bundle != null) {

            if (bundle.getString("title") != null) {
                Intent i = new Intent();
                i.setAction("com.carryapp.CUSTOM_INTENT"); sendBroadcast(i);

                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                MainFragment fragment = new MainFragment();
                fragmentManager.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.mycontainer, fragment, "MAIN_FRAGMENT").commitAllowingStateLoss();

                fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                NoticesFragment fragment3 = new NoticesFragment();
                Bundle bundle1 = new Bundle();
                bundle1.putBoolean("notification",true);
                fragment3.setArguments(bundle1);
                fragmentManager.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.mycontainer, fragment3, "NOTICES_FRAGMENT").addToBackStack("H").commit();


            }

        } else {

            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            MainFragment fragment = new MainFragment();
            fragmentManager.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.mycontainer, fragment, "MAIN_FRAGMENT").commitAllowingStateLoss();
        }
```

Please help with this. Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

> But the question is where should I do this stuff? I am using FCM so
>   onMessageReceived is called when the app is in foreground.

This is because you are sending `notification-messages`.

you have to send data-messages if you want onMessageReceived to be called always.

see the FCM documentation:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages

PS:

> I am sending the notifications from server to my app. I want to keep
>   the count of notifications when notification arrives and I want to
>   show it on the icon ,on text view that I want to make visible with the
>   count of notification.

Standard Android doesn't support the badge on the icon.
Maybe some launcher have it as additional feature, but it's not an Android API.

PPS: Android O introduced the badge, but it also works automatically so no need to change it manually